# ReferenceError: fetch is not defined - Postman

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch, postman

In Postman, I run an arbitrary request. I put the following code in either the
*Pre-req.* script or in the *Tests* script:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3')
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(responseBody => {
    console.log('The response body:');
    console.log(responseBody);
  });
```

When I hit the *Send* button to run the request, I get **ReferenceError: fetch
is not defined**:

[image: ReferenceError: fetch is not defined]

When searching online, I have hardly found anything about this error message
in Postman.
Now, Postman is not a web browser in the normal sense, but just about every
[well known web browser offers the Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API#browser_compatibility)
these days.

Does Postman not implement the Fetch API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Postman not implement the Fetch API?

I think not. The closest correspondence to the `fetch()` command
is `pm.sendRequest()`.
But [*pm.sendRequest* returns a *pm object* and not a Promise](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3927),
at least for now.

I have found a workaround, though.
In the code snippet below I define the `pmFetch()` function which is meant to
do what the `fetch()` command does in a normal web browser.

```js
pmFetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/3')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(responseBody => {
    console.log('The response body:');
    console.log(responseBody);
    console.log('responseBody.title: "' + responseBody.title + '"');
  });
// - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - //
function pmFetch (url) {
  return new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {
    pm.sendRequest(url, function (err, response) {
      if (err) reject(err);
      resolve(response);
    });
  });
}
```

[image: pmFetch mimics the Fetch API]

Here is a [link to the Postman Collection](http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/pmFetch/pmFetch.pm_coll.json)
in case you want to download, import, and run the collection.

#### Reference:

- [How to make *pm.sendRequest* return a Promise](https://community.postman.com/t/how-i-can-set-in-pre-request-script-to-sequence-for-requests/16563/5)