# How can I visualize an API mashup in Postman?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, postman

I have a REST API of classical actors that I want to visualize in Postman.
The image URL of an actor is not in the API, so I will need to create a
mashup from a combination of the core API and another API.

#### 1. Prerequisites

The core API/endpoint is at
http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/actors/actors.json:

```json
{
  "area": {
    "name": "United States",
    "type": null
  },
  "release-groups": [
    {
      "primary-type": "Actor",
      "fullname": "Katharine Hepburn",
      "id": "Q56016",
      "born": "1907"
    },
    {
      "primary-type": "Actor",
      "fullname": "Humphrey Bogart",
      "id": "Q16390",
      "born": "1899"
    }
  ],
  "country": "US",
  "name": "Classical Actors",
  "life-span": {
    "begin": "1899",
    "ended": true,
    "end": "2003"
  }
}
```

The image URLs of *Katharine Hepburn* and *Humphrey Bogart* are at:
http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/actors/coverart/Q56016.json and
http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/actors/coverart/Q16390.json,
respectively.

The corresponding JSONS, Katharine Hepburn:

```json
{
  "images": [
    {
      "front": true,
      "thumbnails": {
        "small": "https://upload.wiki [...] 220px-Tom_cruise_1989.jpg",
        "large": "https://upload.wiki [...] -TomCruiseDec08MTV_cropped.jpg"
      },
      "back": false,
      "edit": 18084161
    },
    {
      "back": true,
      "edit": 39938947,
      "front": false,
      "thumbnails": {
        "small": "https://upload.wiki [...] -Katharine_Hepburn_promo_pic.jpg",
        "large": "https://upload.wiki [...] Tom_Cruise_by_Gage_Skidmore_2.jpg"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

and Humphrey Bogart:

```json
{
  "images": [
    {
      "edit": 40403385,
      "back": true,
      "thumbnails": {
        "small": "https://upload.wiki [...] 220px-Humphrey_Bogart_1940.jpg",
        "large": "https://upload.wiki [...] px-TomCruiseByIanMorris2010.jpg"
      },
      "front": false
    },
    {
      "edit": 40403384,
      "back": false,
      "thumbnails": {
        "small": "https://upload.wiki [...] 220px-Tom_cruise_1989.jpg",
        "large": "https://upload.wiki [...] -TomCruiseDec08MTV_cropped.jpg"
      },
      "front": true
    }
  ]
}
```

where I have truncated the links of the images for better readability.

Note in the core API how each object/person has a unique `id` (`Q56016` for
Katharine Hepburn and `Q16390` for Humphrey Bogart) and a `fullname`.
The other endpoints have – for each object in the `release-groups` array of
the core API – the same unique identifier, along with a link  to an
image/portrait.
Thus, information from all three endpoints is needed to list each actor with a
matching image.

#### 2. The desired resulting mashup

Obviously, the problem is solved if the data in the APIs can be combined
together in such a way that – for each identifier – *both* the name and the
image link are supplied:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Katharine Hepburn",
    "image": "https://upload.wiki [...] -Katharine_Hepburn_promo_pic.jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Humphrey Bogart",
    "image": "https://upload.wiki [...] 220px-Humphrey_Bogart_1940.jpg"
  }
]
```

Then it remains to visualize the data in Postman.

#### 3. Methodology

I will write all code in a single *Tests* script of a Postman request.
That request is just a *dummy* that serves no other purpose than to start
running the *Tests* script.

To construct the mashup and then display the result, it would be convenient to
use the well-known [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and then get the
images by using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

One caveat is that Postman does not implement the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API).
But luckily there is [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67588692)
that explains how to mimic the `fetch()` command in Postman.
It can be done as follows:

```js
function fetch (url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pm.sendRequest(url, function (_, fetchResponse) {
      resolve(fetchResponse);
    });
  });
} // ^^ No Fetch API in Postman! But see https://stackoverflow.com/a/67588692
```

Since this `fetch()` function returns a promise, it should (hopefully) work
the same way as `fetch()` in any modern web browser.

The rest of the *Tests* section should construct the result.
Note how `Promise.all` needs to be chained/nested with the first request
`fetch(urlOuter)` – because it needs data from it.
This is analogous to the second Stack Snippet of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752550).
Finally, the result should be visualized:
<sup>1</sup>

```js
const lock = setTimeout(() => {}, 43210);
const fullnames = [];
const urls = [];
const urlOuter = 'http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/actors/actors.json';
fetch(urlOuter).then(responseO => responseO.json()).then(responseBodyO => {
  const tblHeader = responseBodyO.name;
  const actors = responseBodyO['release-groups'];
  for (const item of actors) {
    fullnames.push(item.fullname);
    urls.push('http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/actors/coverart/' +
        item.id + '.json');
  }
  return Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url)
    .then(responseI => responseI.json())
    .then(responseBodyI => responseBodyI.images.find(obj =>
      obj.back === true).thumbnails.small)))
    .then(imageURLs => {
      clearTimeout(lock); // Unlock the timeout.
      const actorNames = fullnames.map(value => ({ name: value }));
      const actorImages = imageURLs.map(value => ({ image: value }));
      const actorsAndImages = actorNames.map(
        (item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, actorImages[i]));
      console.log('actorsAndImages:\n' + JSON.stringify(actorsAndImages));
      const template = `<table>
        <tr><th>` + tblHeader + `</th></tr>
        {{#each responseI}}
        <tr><td>{{name}}<br><img src="{{image}}"></td></tr>
        {{/each}}
      </table>`;
      pm.visualizer.set(template, { responseI: actorsAndImages });
    });
}).catch(_ => {
  console.error('Failed to fetch - ' + urlOuter);
});
```

In Postman:

[image: Mashup Tests script in Postman]

#### 4. Does it work?

So does it work? – The answer is both yes and no.

- On the good side, I could create the desired JSON mashup result as in
  section 2 above.
- On the bad side, the visualization fails:

[image: Result of Promise.all in Postman]

The message **Set up the visualizer for this request** is typical when the
call to `pm.visualizer.set()` has been forgotten.
But I did *not* forget it. So what is wrong?

#### 5. How to replicate my attempt in Postman

Replicating my attempt in Postman should be straightforward.
Assuming you are using [the desktop version of Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/), do as follows:

1. Download and save
   http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/actors/Promise.all-Actors.pm_coll.json
   in a suitable place on your hard drive.
2. In Postman, *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> > Upload Files >
   `Promise.all-Actors.pm_coll.json` > Import*.
   You should now see `Promise.all-Actors` among your collections in Postman.
3. *Collections > `Promise.all-Actors` > `DummyRequest` > **Send***.
4. In the Postman Response Body, click *Visualize*.
5. Done! – If everything worked as intended, you should now see the output as
   above.

#### References

- [Wikidata on Katharine Hepburn](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q56016)
- [Wikidata on Humphrey Bogart](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q16390)
- [Postman does not implement the Fetch API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67588692)
- [Postman workaround for known bug: chained requests never getting executed](https://community.postman.com/t/using-native-javascript-promises-in-postman/636)
- [How to run nested requests in JavaScript – 2nd snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752550)
- [How can I fetch an array of URLs with Promise.all?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67671337)

---

<sup>1</sup> Don't get confused by the lines
`const lock = setTimeout(() => {}, 43210);` and `clearTimeout(lock);`. –
Their only purpose is to serve as [a workaround for a known bug](https://community.postman.com/t/using-native-javascript-promises-in-postman/636).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The message **Set up the visualizer for this request** is typical when the
> call to `pm.visualizer.set()` has been forgotten.
> But I did *not* forget it. So what is wrong?

As already touched upon, the problem is that
[Postman does not natively support promises](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3927).
<sup>1</sup>
What does that mean? – Well, apparently it means that a function such as
`pm.visualizer.set()` cannot be called from within the *callback of a
Promise*.
It has to be called from within the *callback of `pm.sendRequest()`*.
Note that by the construction of the `fetch()` function the corresponding
Promise is actually *outside* of the `pm.sendRequest()` callback!

#### 1. Achieving the desired result *and* visualizing it

In other words, you need to replace all occurrences of `fetch()` with
`pm.sendRequest()`.
You also need to implement your own version of `Promise.all`, since it relies
upon promises, something you don't have in a native Postman script.
Fortunately, such an implementation was posted in
[an answer the day before yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67792583).

After making those changes, here is the code for the *Tests* section, starting
with the initializations:
<sup>2</sup>

```js
const lock = setTimeout(() => {}, 43210);
const fullnames = [];
const urls = [];
const urlOuter = 'http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/actors/actors.json';
```

The main part – slightly unconventionally formatted – to avoid vertical
scrolling:

```js
pm.sendRequest(urlOuter, (_, responseO) => {
  const tblHeader = responseO.json().name;
  const actors = responseO.json()['release-groups'];
  for (const item of actors) {
    fullnames.push(item.fullname);
    urls.push('http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/actors/coverart/' +
        item.id + '.json'); }
  const images = [];
  let countDown = urls.length;
  urls.forEach((url, index) => {
    asynchronousCall(url, imageURL => {
      images[index] = imageURL;
      if (--countDown === 0) { // Callback for ALL starts on next line.
        clearTimeout(lock); // Unlock the timeout.
        const actorNames = fullnames.map(value => ({ name: value }));
        const actorImages = images.map(value => ({ image: value }));
        const actorsAndImages = actorNames.map(
          (item, i) => Object.assign({}, item, actorImages[i]));
        console.log('actorsAndImages:\n' + JSON.stringify(actorsAndImages));
        const template = `<table>
          <tr><th>` + tblHeader + `</th></tr>
          {{#each responseI}}
          <tr><td>{{name}}<br><img src="{{image}}"></td></tr>
          {{/each}}
        </table>`;
        pm.visualizer.set(template, { responseI: actorsAndImages });
      }
    });
  });
  function asynchronousCall (url, callback) {
    pm.sendRequest(url, (_, responseI) => {
      callback(responseI.json().images.find(obj => obj.back === true)
        .thumbnails.small); // Individual callback.
    }); } });
```

In Postman:

[image: Mashup Tests script in Postman]

#### 2. Does it work?

Yes! – It works:

[image: Result of Promise.all in Postman]

#### 3. How to replicate my solution in Postman

Assuming you are using [the desktop version of Postman](https://www.postman.com/downloads/), do as follows:

1. Download and save
   http://henke.atwebpages.com/postman/actors/Actors.pm_coll.json
   in a suitable place on your hard drive.
2. In Postman, *<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> > Upload Files >
   `Actors.pm_coll.json` > Import*.
3. *Collections > `Actors` > `DummyRequest` > **Send***.
4. In the Postman Response Body, click *Visualize*.
5. Done! – You should now see the output as above.

#### References

- [`pm.sendRequest` returns a *pm object* – not a Promise](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3927)
- [How to fetch an array of URLs *without* Promise.all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67792583)

---

<sup>1</sup> I hope Postman *will* support promises in a future version.
<sup>2</sup> Again, don't get confused by the lines
`const lock = setTimeout(() => {}, 43210);` and `clearTimeout(lock);`. –
Their only purpose is to serve as [a workaround for a known bug](https://community.postman.com/t/using-native-javascript-promises-in-postman/636).